# Why I am getting this exception with Google CAlendar library using java?

Tags: java, exception, google-calendar-api

I just tried to compile a small prog for testing purposes in java. I added the Google Calendar library and to test whether it works I tried the following codes.

```
package googlemaptest;

import com.google.gdata.client.calendar.CalendarService;
import com.google.gdata.client.calendar.CalendarService.Versions;

/**
 *
 * @author vimal
 */
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("VErsion testing ..........."+CalendarService.CALENDAR_SERVICE );
        System.out.println("VErsion testing ..........."+CalendarService.DEFAULT_VERSION  );// this is line 24 in my codes
    }

}
```

I expected it to return me the calendar version and its name but in return it returned me something like this:

```
VErsion testing ...........cl
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code
        at googlemaptest.Main.main(Main.java:24)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I profiled the file and it came up wd the following exceptions

init:
profile-init:
Deleting: D:\Program Files\NetBeans 6.8\googleMapTEst\build\built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: D:\Program Files\NetBeans 6.8\googleMapTEst\build\built-jar.properties
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: D:\Program Files\NetBeans 6.8\googleMapTEst\build\built-clean.properties
Deleting directory D:\Program Files\NetBeans 6.8\googleMapTEst\build
clean:
Created dir: D:\Program Files\NetBeans 6.8\googleMapTEst\build\classes
Created dir: D:\Program Files\NetBeans 6.8\googleMapTEst\build\empty
Compiling 1 source file to D:\Program Files\NetBeans 6.8\googleMapTEst\build\classes
compile-single:
profile-single:
Profiler Agent: Waiting for connection on port 5140, timeout 10 seconds (Protocol version: 9)
Profiler Agent: Established local connection with the tool
VErsion testing ...........cl
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Maps
        at com.google.gdata.wireformats.AltRegistry.(AltRegistry.java:118)
        at com.google.gdata.wireformats.AltRegistry.(AltRegistry.java:100)
        at com.google.gdata.client.Service.(Service.java:555)
        at googlemaptest.Main.main(Main.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.Maps
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
        ... 4 more
Profiler Agent: Connection with agent closed
Profiler Agent: Connection with agent closed
Profiler Agent: Initializing...
Profiler Agent: Options: >D:\Program Files\NetBeans 6.8\profiler3\lib,5140,10<
Profiler Agent: Initialized succesfully
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)

Since I am using this library for the first time, I do not have much knowledge about the exception. Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how I can sort this out?

Comment: How are you compiling and running the program?

Comment: Main.java:24 is pointing outside your code. could you please show the line the build fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message means that there was a compiler error. But the code looks fine. Perhaps it is outdated? In Eclipse: Try Project | Clean.

Eclipse will tell you about compile errors in the "Problems View" (Not the "Error View which is for bugs in Eclipse itself). You can open it with Window | Show View | Problems.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you're trying to run the code in Eclipse, which does let you run code which hasn't actually compiled successfully.

*Look at the compiler errors*. They will help you out.